# Problema 'Unexpected token 1fr'

Tags: html, css, brackets

buenas noches.
Estoy intentando poner 4 columnas por separado. El problema que al escribirlo como se ve en la imagen, me dice que hay un error 'Unexpected token 1fr'(me pasa lo mismo al usar metodo repeat(4, 1fr)). Muchas gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código completo va como texto por favor

Comment: Es probable que el editor que estás usando no reconoce la propiedad `grid-template-columns` y por eso el error. Qué editor estás usando? El código no está funcionando como corresponde?

Comment: El codigo funciona, sin embargo me da error. Utilizo brackets. Puede ser que necesite algun plugin o algo similar?Gracias por responder!